# Activate plugins on project level

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using the [atomic-icon](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10044-atom-material-icons) plugin and feel like it's really nice on one project I'm using but it's not ideal for another project.
Anyone knows if it's possible to activate/disable plugins on project level instead of the general IDE level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currenlty it's not possible. Please vote for the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205289